# How do I link to another directory with python?

Tags: python, web, jinja2

In blog.py
template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**), 'templates')

^I know this is the way to search for the templates folder in the same directory, but what about sibling directories (i.e. other folders of the current folder's parent)

The problem is:

Current File
WebAppName/Backend/blog.py

How Do I Reference?
WebAppName/Frontend/templates/

What should I change template_dir to in order to access templates in the Frontend folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template_dir = os.path.abspath(
               os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                            '../Frontend/templates'))
```

Comment: Thank you, so the ".." basically accesses the current folder's parent. Right?

Comment: Yes, the `..` refers to the directory's parent. The `os.path.abspath` is not strictly necessary, but it will make `template_dir` more readable.